# MySQL and PHP fetch particular student who pass the exam

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL table name: Student
Fields: id,name,subject1,subject2,subject3.

Need to filter out the students who has more than 150 marks in total.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT id, (SUM(subject1)+SUM(subject2)+SUM(subject3)) AS total FROM student GROUP BY id
```

You can check `if(total > 150)` in mysql query..

Comment: You mean `having total > 150`

Comment: need to filter out student who have total of 150 or above.